# Android drops WiFi connection if that doesn't provide internet access

Tags: android, wifi

I'm developing a server-client app using Raspberry as server and AP and android in client side. However, Android drops and reconnect connection constantly.

I would like to avoid this problem withouth a root required solution, do you know the way?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the you are connected to an hotspot that does not allow you to access the Internet? Something is wrong with your app. Android does not drop the connection if it doesn't provide internet access

Comment: `Android drops and reconnect connection constantly`. No. Not normally. Maybe if the device is a phone. Switch off mobile connection.

Comment: @kingston I'm connecting the Wi-Fi AP manually, my App only connect the socket. I've read more cases like this, but with no solution if you aren't root.

Comment: can you point me to the other cases you found?

Comment: @kingston http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131132/force-marshmallow-to-keep-a-wi-fi-without-internet-access   http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130265/stay-connected-to-specific-wifi-which-has-no-internet